# I am trying to send data but unable to find the error jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my index, and I want to send form data without redirecting to another page I want to add  details with out refresh by using ajax j query.

Is my jQuery library correct..?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(#button).click(function(){
        $.post("jq.php",{
            fname:$('#fname').val(),
            lname:$('#lname').val()
        },
        function(data){
            $('#results').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>  
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">First Name</br>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">Last Name</br>
<button id="button">Submit</button></br>
<textarea id="results" style="width:100 height:200> </textarea>
```

and this is action page

```php
$fname=$_post['fname'];
$lname=$_post['fname'];

echo "$fname  $lname";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST` is not `$_post` change this

```
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['fname'];

echo "$fname  $lname";
```

Also you forgot to close `"` here

```
<textarea id="results" style="width:100;height:200;"> </textarea>
```

And change here too, use quotes

```
$("#button").click(function(){
```

Complete code will look like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="test" action="">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">First Name</br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">Last Name</br>
    <button id="button">Submit</button></br>
    <textarea id="results" style="width:100 height:200"> </textarea>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(){
            $.post("index1.php",{
                fname:$('#fname').val(),
                lname:$('#lname').val()
            },
            function(data){
                $('#results').val(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Also change in `textarea`

Comment: Added " still not coming

Comment: do you have this js file `jquery-1.12.4.min.js` ? in same folder

Comment: ok And change here too, use quotes   `$("#button").click(function(){`

Comment: use this to include jquery : <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: i cant copy your full link